# Some good resources for learning F# please

Tags: .net, f#

I am a .Net programmer(both C# and VB.net) , and I want to go into F# area also, but can't find some good online article/pdf to start with. Please guide me through this.

Comment: This is a good staring point. Also good suggestions from everyone else. Thanks a ton, everyone

Comment: Related question (and better answers): http://stackoverflow.com/q/734525

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[hubFS: THE place for F#](http://cs.hubfs.net/)

[hubFS: THE place for F# » Establish skills in F# » Books, Tutorials, links and other resources](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/88/ShowForum.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Check the MSDN F# Development center, they have some articles on there:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/default.aspx

Answer (score 4):

[Robert Pickering](http://www.strangelights.com/blog/) who wrote [Foundations of F#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597575) has a blog you could check.

[Don Syme](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/), lead designer of the F# language also has one. He co-wrote the [Expert F#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598504) book as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great series of articles called "[F# for game development](http://sharp-gamedev.blogspot.com/2008/09/introduction.html)" which explains F# step by step. The good thing about the articles is that they are written by a beginner and shows how he learns F#.

Another good resours is the "[Exploring the F# Language](http://www.gotnet.biz/Blog/post/Kevin-Hazzards-Exploring-the-FSharp-Language-Series-Part1-What-is-FSharp.aspx)" articles which explains F# from a developer point of view.

Hanselman has a few  resources mentioned [Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode34TheRiseOfF.aspx) you should have a look on the great presentation called "[F# Eye for the C# Guy](http://www.slideshare.net/gueste3f83d/f-eye-for-the-c-guy-presentation?type=powerpoint)" that really helped me understand F#.